# Log4Net.Async issue in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, log4net

I keep receiving following error:

```
log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [AsyncLog4NetAppender] of type [Log4Net.Async.ParallelForwardingAppender]. Reported error follows.
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type [Log4Net.Async.ParallelForwardingAppender]. Tried assembly [log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a] and all loaded assemblies
   at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(Assembly relativeAssembly, String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(XmlElement appenderElement)
log4net:ERROR Appender named [AsyncLog4NetAppender] not found.
```

**Packages config**

```
<package id="log4net" version="2.0.8" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Log4Net.Async" version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net451" />
```

**Web config**

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.8.0" newVersion="2.0.8.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

When I remove the `log4net.async` nuget package and add it again it works. But after some time I get this error again.

Comment: Add an explicit reference to the `Log4Net.Async` assembly by referencing a class in it in your code. This will force the build process to load the assembly (I suspect it isn't seeing a reference to it and optimizing it away)

Comment: You mean just adding the namespace in one of my classes?

Comment: I'm not sure that's enough as the compiler may optimize it away as it isn't used. I seem to remember in a similar circumstance adding a field of a type in the assembly would do it.

Comment: Agreed, adding a namespace reference won't do much.  Show us your appender configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (probably) need to add the assembly name to your appender reference.

```
<appender name="AsyncLog4NetAppender" type="Log4Net.Async.ParallelForwardingAppender,Log4Net.Async">
```

Note the part after the comma, `Log4Net.Async`.

Adding the name of the reference assembly should tell .Net how to find the class in the appropriate assembly.